# Popup intended to display ProgressBar not showing in JavaFX

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, popup, progress-bar

I want to display a `ProgressBar` using a `Popup` in JavaFX so that I will be able to make the `ProgressBar` disappear by calling the `PopUp`'s `hide()` method. However, rather than disappearing when the background task is complete, the `ProgessBar` doesn't show at all.

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Popup;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();

        Popup popup = new Popup();
        ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar();
        popup.getContent().add(bar);

        Task<Void> task = new Task<>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                        updateProgress(i, 100);
                    } catch (Exception ignored) {
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        };

        bar.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
        task.setOnSucceeded(workerStateEvent -> popup.hide());
        popup.show(stage);
        new Thread(task).start();

        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 100, 100));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

When I run the above code, all I see is a blank stage, shown here:
[image: Blank stage in place of ProgressBar]

If I add the `ProgressBar` to the `Stage` manually using `root.getChildren().add(bar)`, the bar displays correctly, with its `progressProperty` properly bonded, so I know that the issue is with the `Popup`. However, using that method, the bar doesn't disappear when the background task is complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find this documented anywhere, but I think the owner of a `Popup` must be showing for the `Popup.show(owner)` method to succeed. So the following reordering of your code (calling `stage.show()` before `popup.show(stage)`) works:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    StackPane root = new StackPane();

    Popup popup = new Popup();
    ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar();
    popup.getContent().add(bar);

    Task<Void> task = new Task<>() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                    updateProgress(i, 100);
                } catch (Exception ignored) {
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

    bar.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
    task.setOnSucceeded(workerStateEvent -> popup.hide());

    stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 100, 100));
    stage.show();
    
    popup.show(stage);
    new Thread(task).start();

}
```

Note your other approach works: you just have to remove the progress bar from the scene graph when the task is complete:

```
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();

//        Popup popup = new Popup();
        
        ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar();
//        popup.getContent().add(bar);
        root.getChildren().add(bar);

        Task<Void> task = new Task<>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                        updateProgress(i, 100);
                    } catch (Exception ignored) {
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        };

        bar.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
//        task.setOnSucceeded(workerStateEvent -> popup.hide());
        task.setOnSucceeded(event -> root.getChildren().remove(bar));

        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 100, 100));
        stage.show();

        
//        popup.show(stage);
        new Thread(task).start();

    }
```

Comment: It works. Thanks. Can't accept it just now because I edited the question a few minutes ago.